# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded building Chromium

Tags: json, chromium

When building chromium with this

```
autoninja -C out/Debug chrome
```

I get this errors:

```
[915/51478] ACTION //components/resources:about_credits(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x86)
FAILED: gen/components/resources/about_credits.html
C:/Users/duyvk/chromium/depot_tools/bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../tools/licenses.py --target-os=win --depfile gen/components/resources/about_credits.d credits gen/components/resources/about_credits.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../../tools/licenses.py", line 870, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "../../tools/licenses.py", line 855, in main
    args.depfile):
  File "../../tools/licenses.py", line 693, in GenerateCredits
    extra_third_party_dirs)
  File "../../tools/licenses.py", line 533, in FindThirdPartyDirs
    ProcessAdditionalReadmePathsJson(root, dirpath, third_party_dirs)
  File "../../tools/licenses.py", line 504, in ProcessAdditionalReadmePathsJson
    extra_paths = json.load(paths_file)
  File "C:\Users\duyvk\chromium\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python\bin\lib\json\__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\duyvk\chromium\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python\bin\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\duyvk\chromium\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python\bin\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\duyvk\chromium\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python\bin\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
[932/51478] ACTION //third_party/blink/renderer/bindings:generate_bindings_all(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x86)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed
```

I have done some googling but I can't find any solutions.
I'm using Visual Studio 19.

Comment: Did you run `gclient sync` before trying to build Chromium?

Comment: Yes I did run 'gclient sync'

Comment: You should also post the Chormium build flags that you may have passed when compiling it